# Odoo 11 : want to implement bills of raw materials depending on sale.order model

Tags: model, odoo, record

I am very new to Odoo and get stuck often. Now, I am really stucked with no solution in mind.
**My goal** is to count consummed raw materials.
**The problem** is that I want to initialise a model (here assessment.raw.material) with the product_id in mrp.bom.line. I tried with "default=", ".create()" but it doesn't work.
I think that if I get all product_id of all raw materials, i can easily fill all column with sql queries.
Can you help me?
Or i get it wrong?
Or Do you have better idea? Thank you. Sorry for my bad english.

```
class AssessmentRawMaterials(models.Model):
    _name = 'assessment.raw.materials'


    # get the product_id from mrp.bom.line
    # which is nomenclature of each
    # finished product
    product_id = fields.Many2one(
        string='Matières premières',
        comodel_name='mrp.bom.line',
        ondelete="no action",
        store=True
   )

    # get the product unit of measure
    # by calling the variable name of 
    # product_id
    product_uom_name = fields.Char(
        string=u'Unité de mesure',
        related='product_id.product_id.name'
   )

    # compute using sql query, 
    # long long 
    # inner join
    # from sale.order to mrp.bom.line
    raw_material_qty = fields.Integer(
       string=u'Quantité de matières premières',
       default=0
   )
```

Comment: Could you please share more information about the model relations? First thing to notice: you have a field `product_id` which isn't a product but a bom line. That's feels just wrong. How do you create records of model `assesment.raw.materials`?

Comment: There is just one relation (many2one) between the two models (assessment.raw.material and mrp.bom.line), I just want to copy the column **product_id** of mrp.bom.line to **product_id** of assessment.raw.materials. And record creation in **assessment.raw.materials** is not user input but must be automatic and auto updated.

Comment: Please edit your question if possible. You can use related fields for that, i will write a short answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one-to-one like relation between bom line and assessment raw material and want to user the bom lines product information, use related fields:

```py
bom_line_id = fields.Many2one(
    string='Matières premières',
    comodel_name='mrp.bom.line',
    ondelete="no action")  # store not needed default True
product_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='product.product',
    related='bom_line_id.product_id',
    store=True)  # store explanation for related fields after code
```

On normal many2one fields the store parameter is per default `True`. On related fields you really need to decide what should happen in the database:

1. setting `store=True` will create a new column on your `assessment_raw_materials` table and will Odoo tell to copy the value from `product_product` table everytime it changes. So it is a bit redundant but sometimes wished for.
2. setting `store=False` will not create a new column, but instead Odoo will always get the value from `product_product` table.

Comment: It's better than i did. But now, how to i add all those bom_id automatically? And bom_id (i think the product, is still redondant), how to deal with that? Thank you.

Comment: A bom line is not a product but always a part of a bom with information about a product (sub-product) and mostly a quantity as very simple example. I don't know the process of your global goal/requirement, that's why i was asking for more information in your question. Actually, i don't know what you're trying there ;-)

Comment: I reedited my post. We agree that we need raw materials (I think the list is located in mrp.bom.line) to build product (we talk the true product "finished product"). **My goal** is to count those consummed raw materials according to sale order which trigger the manufacturing order to build the true product.

Comment: I'm just wondering, did you look into https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/12.0/manufacturing.html how to use BoMs in Odoo?

Comment: No, i didn't. The project manager just give me 3 weeks to learn odoo and I just followed the tutorial here [link](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/backend.html) and read relevant pages (according to me) of this book : Odoo 11 Development Cookbook - Second Edition - Alexandre Fayolle & Holger Brunn

Comment: You will probably just reinvent the wheel without basic functional knowledge about Odoo apps/modules. In this case Sale and Manufacturing knowledge should be enough to get rolling ;-) Does the project manager even know anything about Odoo?

Comment: Can you tell me where i can find that functionnality? But i think the best question is where can i find a summary of all functionnalities avaible in each modules? I think a good one, but not good at talking :D

Comment: You should start [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/12.0/index.html). It's the user documentation for Odoo 12, but you can change the version on the upper right corner. For Odoo partners there is a training center with lots of stuff, but you have to be a partner for that.